# Get text from auto complete field

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html-agility-pack

i try to make a tool get information from etsy.com and i have some problem.

U can go to etsy.com then type something in search input, they will auto complete

I dont know how to get them use HTML agility pack, do u have any idea?

http://s17.postimg.org/5ogqo04in/searc.png
Image for every one can see.

How can i get data when submited some text from same page.

Here is code in search input text i got.

```
<form id="search-bar" action="http://www.etsy.com/search.php" method="GET">
 <div class="search-bar-holder">
 <input value="belly button jewelry" autocomplete="off" id="autocomplete-field" name="search_query" class="autocomplete text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" data-as-disable="" tabindex="0" type="text"><div style="top: 34px; left: 0px; width: 398px; display: block; opacity: 1;" id="search-suggestions">
                                <ul class="clear">
```

Thanks for your reading. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using ajax for autofilling the text box. they call the url

```
http://www.etsy.com/suggestions_ajax.php?version=&search_query=hello&search_type=all&hp_ref=primary
```

you can search it with changing the

> search_query

it will return a json response.